# Year and series in parenthesis, joined and on their own

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm currently writing a paper and my supervisor has given me specific citation rules but no template.

One of the rules is:

Year is set in parentheses, but when the item is part of a series, both are in one set of parentheses separated with a comma.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, 12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % Language specification

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Required to output umlauts in a PDF
\usepackage{pslatex}

% bibliography and citation management


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \clearlist{publisher}%  
    \clearlist{location}%
}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearlist{publisher}%  
    \clearlist{location}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}  
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
    @Book{zimmermann1973judeneid,
        Title                    = {Die Entwicklung des Judeneids},
        Author                   = {Volker Zimmermann},
        Publisher                = {Peter Lang},
        Year                     = {1973},
        Series                   = {Europäische Hochschulschriften. Reihe I. Deutsche Literatur und Germanistik},
        number                   = {56},

        Location                 = {Frankfurt am Main},
        Subtitle                 = {Untersuchungen und Texte zur rechtlichen und sozialen Stellung der Juden im Mittelalter}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \null\vfill
    Some text\footcite{zimmermann1973judeneid}

    \printbibliography[title={Literatur}]

\end{document}
```

It now looks like

[image]

It should look like *with* `series`

[image]

And for a item *without* `series` it should look like (but **without** the dot after the subtitle/title and before the year)

[image]

Thank you very much for any help and suggestions!

Comment: The apparent inconsistency of the position of `publisher` and `location` w.r.t. the year in parentheses is desired?

Comment: Apparently these two information should not be displayed at all. I am contacting my supervisor regarding this matter. I changed the MWE and the screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to adjust the main bibliography drivers to get what you want. Open up the file `standard.bbx` and have a look for the block beginning with `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}`. Copy this block to your preamble and adjust it to what you want.

You could also use `\xpatchbibdriver` from the `xpatch` package to just patch the driver.

The relevant section of the driver is:

```
\usebibmacro{series+number}% 
\newunit\newblock 
\printfield{note}% 
\newunit\newblock 
\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
```

To remove the publisher and location, and put the series, number, and date in parentheses, we want this instead:

```
\printfield{note}%
\setunit{\addspace}\newblock
\printtext[parens]{%
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}}%
```

We can either include the whole driver in the preamble as in the MWE below, or, if this is the only change you need to make, it can be easier to patch it like this:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}% 
   \newunit\newblock 
   \printfield{note}% 
   \newunit\newblock 
   \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}
  {\printfield{note}%
   \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
   \printtext[parens]{%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{date}}}
  {}
  {}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{zimmermann1973judeneid,
  author    = {Zimmermann, Volker},
  title     = {Die Entwicklung des Judeneids},
  subtitle  = {Untersuchungen und Texte zur rechtlichen und sozialen Stellung der Juden im Mittelalter},
  series    = {Europäische Hochschulschriften. Reihe I. Deutsche Literatur und Germanistik},
  number    = {56},
  location  = {Frankfurt am Main},
  publisher = {Peter Lang},
  date      = {1973}
}
@book{zimmermann1973judeneid-noseries,
  author    = {Zimmermann, Volker},
  title     = {Die Entwicklung des Judeneids},
  subtitle  = {Untersuchungen und Texte zur rechtlichen und sozialen Stellung der Juden im Mittelalter},
  location  = {Frankfurt am Main},
  publisher = {Peter Lang},
  date      = {1973}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Some text \autocite{zimmermann1973judeneid}.
Some text \autocite{zimmermann1973judeneid-noseries}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I assume a similar change is desired for `@inbook`, `@collection` and `@incollection` and (a structurally similar patch) possibly even for other types as well, so using `xpatch` and looping through the types to be patched looks like a very attractive option here.

Comment: It should be noted that the new code works under the assumption that at least one of `year` (`date`), `series` or `number` is given. For `@book`s and `@book`-like entries that is quite a reasonable assumption.